# How to load simple text file with float number matrix / table into Scilab

Tags: scilab

MATLAB and Octave use load and transfer the contents into a matrix variable with the same name. The Scilab load command does not do the same. Also loadmatfile does something different. On some website it was said to use a loop to read in the data. What is the simplest way to get the text data file into a matrix in Scilab?

I asked the question on 'Computational Science', but they suggested this would be the right place.

I understand a variable needs to not be empty. But it is a file and not a variable yet. When I assigned 0 to the filename it actually deleted the contents of the file and wrote 0 to it?

I also understand a file has to be opened first.

I tried many commands and I am getting confused. In Matlab and Octave it is very simple.

If someone could give a suggestion (actual code) I can post the results.

Comment: @gariepy: I had scilab and matlab before, but when I hit the post button it said I am not allowed to create a custom tag, because of my low reputation (something along that line).

Comment: That is strange...the `scilab` tag has been around for years, so I'm not sure why you encountered that issue.  At any rate, I changed it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### fscanfMat

[fscanfMat](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/fscanfMat.html) is what you are looking for.

Given below file (my_data.txt):

```
 my comment about my data
 0.91  0.82  0.86  0.67  0.30 
 0.55  0.06  0.25  0.34  0.53 
 0.60  0.11  0.48  0.90  0.12 
 0.93  0.23  0.68  0.07  0.85 
 0.93  0.86  0.86  0.69  0.09
```

The following would print:

```
-->[my_mat,txt]=fscanfMat("./my_data.txt")
 txt  =

  my comment about my data   
 my_mat  =

    0.91    0.82    0.86    0.67    0.3   
    0.55    0.06    0.25    0.34    0.53  
    0.6     0.11    0.48    0.9     0.12  
    0.93    0.23    0.68    0.07    0.85  
    0.93    0.86    0.86    0.69    0.09
```

**Note**

- The first non-numeric lines of the file are returned in text if requested (so optional, for any comments for instance)
- All the remaining lines must have the same number of columns.
- Column separator are assumed to be either white spaces or tab characters, if there are the both, white spaces are chosen by default.
- The number of columns of the matrix will follow the number of columns found in the file.
- The number of lines is fetched by detecting eof in the input file.
- It supports files encoded as ANSI/ASCII and UTF-8.
- Optionally you can control parsing with format string (see [scanf_conversion](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/scanf_conversion.html) docs)

Comment: I had a parallel post on Computational Science, where I posted the solution I found yesterday. It got migrated 3 hrs ago.

Comment: If that answer was better please post it here and accept that. Always interrested in better solutions :).

Comment: (I hit enter again..) Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328453/how-to-load-simple-text-file-with-float-number-matrix-table-into-scilab. But 'fscanfmat' works simpler and better, and I don't get a NAN column. Thank you! I tried this command before, but I couldn't get the syntax right. Also I was confused, because in one tutorial I read, that the file has to be 'opened' first.