# How to load simple text file with float number matrix / table into Scilab

Tags: matlab

MATLAB and Octave use load  and transfer the contents into a matrix variable with the same name. The Scilab load command does not do the same. Also loadmatfile does something different.
On some website it was said to use a loop to read in the data.
What is the simplest way to get the text data file into a matrix in Scilab?

(This is the first time asking a question on SE, so please bear with me.)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. This question is off-topic here, since it address a specific problem in a specific software. It may be better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you tried with [``fscanfMat``](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/fscanfMat.html) or [``csvRead``](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/csvRead.html)?

Comment: !--error 4 
Undefined variable: test

Comment: That went too fast. I always get this error. How can I define a variable that is a file somewhere? I tried fscanfMat and csvRead. I understand a variable cannot be empty, but it is a file not in the workspace yet?

Comment: If this the wrong place can it be 'moved' to Stackoverflow. Or do I start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution.

The file is in this format:

```
15924.238000 20873.314000 16501.114000
15927.280000 20817.124000 16499.614000
...
```

So the numbers are space separated.

The commands are:

```
filename = '/home/um/Documents/testfile.dat'
M = csvRead(filename,ascii(32), '.', 'double')
disp(M)
```

The output is:

```
15924.238    20873.314    16501.114    Nan  
15927.28     20817.124    16499.614    Nan
...
```

This is more complicated than 'load filename' and it creates a 4th Nan column.

So, if someone knows a better way, please.